# Cannot list host OS FileZilla server directory using VirtualBox guest OS client

Tags: virtualbox, ftp

I'd like to access an FTP server on the host OS from the guest OS. The FTP server works on win7, I can access it using Firefox, I can read the shared folder with the guest user. On the other hand it is very hard to access it from the guest OS, which is win98 and I use IE6 as client. I disabled security as much as possible (disabled password, ip checking, allowing unencoded messages), in theory it connects to the server, but still I got this weird error message. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In theory this 425 is typical when a client tries active mode and a firewall blocks the data connection opened by the server to the direction of the client. According to Microsoft IE5 has passive mode support, so my IE6 should have it too. I checked and this feature does not seem to be added to Win98 Internet Explorers, probably it was added to Win2000 or later. What I know that Windows Server 2003 docs claimed this. Since Win98 does not have a firewall and I turned off the firewall in the host OS too, I was not sure that using active mode is the actual cause. I tried out port forwarding in VirtualBox too, but there is not much info around about which ports to forward, and the ports I tried did not make a difference. I decided to install total commander and try passive mode, which should not be affected by any firewall. It was a surprise, that even TC in passive mode timeouts when I try it from the guest OS. So I doubt that the problem is caused by active mode. It should be something VirtualBox specific. I did not find any solution for it, so I decided to give up and solve this on HTTP instead.

Note:
Probably the same phenomenon stops me from connecting to a win98 file sharing. The win7 discovers that the machine is on the network, the legacy protocol is allowed, but still it cannot connect. I think I should look around in the "VirtualBox+NAT+timeout" topic, maybe I find something. But I am afraid this is some kind of bug and it cannot be solved. I tried bridged mode too, but I lose internet and network with that. In theory I'd need MS loopback adapter, but if I cannot solve this with NAT, then there is no point to push it further.